# URL Rewrite ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

i have an asp.net website where i need to use URL re-write so i have written an HTTP module and i have implemented it and it works correctly the only problem is when the page redirect to its corresponding address the images and the styles are not loaded.

here is the http module:

// Your BeginRequest event handler.

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    string URL = application.Request.Url.ToString();
    //int pid = Convert.ToInt32(application.Request.QueryString["pid"]);

    if ((URL.ToLower().Contains(".aspx"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".js"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".css"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".gif"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".png"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".jpeg"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".jpe"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".jpg"))
        || (URL.ToLower().Contains(".ashx")))
        return;
    else
    {
        string mname = URL.Substring(URL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToString();

        Merchand ms = merchantDB.GetMerchant(mname);

        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        if (ms != null)
        {

            string url = "~/pages/Merchant.aspx?mid=" + ms.MerchandID + "&catid=" + ms.MainCategory + "&subcatid=0";
            context.RewritePath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(url));
        }
        else
        {
            //("");
            string url = "~/pages/default.aspx";
            context.RewritePath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(url));
        }
    }

}
```

when i open the page from it normal URL it opens fine, but when i use the url rewrite it open but with out images or styles.

when i open firebug i get an error that the css and the javascript are not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make rewrite work with IIS, do the following:

1. Register the httpmodule in web.config in the system.webserver tag:

> ```
> <modules>
> <add name="Rewrite" type="Rewrite"/>
> </modules>
> ```

1. change this: context.RewritePath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(url)); to this: context.RewritePath(url, false);
2. make your images runat server and put their path as ~/images/imagename